# JS iterate over an object and remove the enabled false

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic object with the following structure:

```
{
 a: {
  someKey: {
    propOne: '',
    enabled: true
  }
 },
 b: {
  someKey: {
    propOne: '',
    enabled: false
  }
 },
c: {
  someKey: {
    propOne: '',
    enabled: false
  }
 },
   someKey: {
      ab: {
        propOne: '',
        enabled: true
      }
     }
    }
```

I need to remove the tree with the `enabled` false. So in the above example the result should be:

```
 const result = {
     a: {
      someKey: {
        propOne: '',
        enabled: true
      }
     },


   d: {
      someKey: {
        propOne: '',
        enabled: true
      }
     }
    }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use filter function to get new array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive check for a property `enabled` with the value `false` and delete this branch from the object.

```js
function deleteKey(object) {
    Object
        .keys(object)
        .forEach(function (key) {
            if (object[key].enabled === false) {
                delete object[key];
                return;
            }
            if (object[key] && typeof object[key] === 'object') {
                deleteKey(object[key]);
                if (!Object.keys(object[key]).length) {
                    delete object[key];
                }
            }
        });
}

var object = { name: "WHITE_THEME", source: "WHITE_THEME", page: { layout: { grid: "TILES", margin: { enabled: true, left: 15, top: 15, right: 15, bottom: 15 } }, background: { filter: { enabled: false, blur: { enabled: false, value: null, unit: "px" }, brightness: { enabled: false, value: 100, unit: "%" }, contrast: { enabled: false, value: 0, unit: "%" }, grayscale: { enabled: false, value: 0, unit: "%" }, invert: { enabled: false, value: 0, unit: "%" }, opacity: { enabled: false, value: 100, unit: "%" }, saturate: { enabled: false, value: 100, unit: "%" } }, color: { enabled: false, value: "rgba(232, 232, 232, 1)" } } } };

deleteKey(object);

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working with nested structure. Take a look https://jsbin.com/xibifiracu/edit?js,output please.

Comment: maybe you add on which level of the wanted/unwanted key the relevant information is to find. please add to a original structure the wanted result as well.

Comment: my problem is actually how to determin to which key the following enabled is assigned. maybe you could add some use cases to the question.

Comment: You should check every object in the tree, if it's have it's own property of enabled then if false remove it.

Answer (score 0):

With lodash:

```
result = _.filter(test, o => o.ab.enabled)
```

Comment: This are not the only keys, the object is dynamic and can contain more keys. I can't use static keys.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `delete` :

```
   var atocken = {
     a: {
      ab: {
        propOne: '',
        enabled: true
      }
     },
     b: {
      ab: {
        propOne: '',
        enabled: false
      }
     }
    }

    if(atocken.b.ab.enabled === false)
    {
      delete atocken.b;
    }
```